# how to get configurable product price in recently viewed product in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, recently-viewed, finalpricebox

> final_price.js to may be not loading this template how to solve it?
> anyne help me to find this solution

```
<if args="isSalable($row())">
<if args="getRegularPrice($row())">
    <span css="'old-price': hasSpecialPrice($row()), 'regular-price': !hasSpecialPrice($row())">
        <span class="price-container"
              css="getAdjustmentCssClasses($row())">
            <span if="label && hasSpecialPrice($row())"
                  class="price-label"
                  text="label"/>

            <span class="price-wrapper"
                  css="priceWrapperCssClasses"
                  attr="priceWrapperAttr"
                  data-price-amount=""
                  data-price-type=""
                  html="getRegularPrice($row())"/>

            <if args="!hasSpecialPrice($row())">
                <each args="data: getAdjustments(), as: '$adj'">
                    <render args="$adj.getBody()"/>
                </each>
            </if>
        </span>
            
        <span class="percent-discount" html="getPercentDiscount($row())"/>
    </span>
</if>
</if>
```

> this template not loaded for configurable porduct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this type of situation could happen if configurable product's simple product qty = 0 or not correctly added scenario. Because I assume `isSalable($row())` will check its simple product's stock qty. Otherwise, it will not show the template content.

[image]